# Where do I create and use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, TimerTask, or Handler?

Tags: android, handler, threadpool, timertask, scheduledexecutorservice

I need to make my RSS Feed reader check the feed every 10 minutes for new posts, and then parse them if there are new ones. I also need to update the UI about every minute.

I have read and heard different things from various sources. My current understanding is that I can use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to make two scheduled threads, and one of them needs a `Handler` for updating the UI. I am unsure about what the most efficient use of these classes or `TimerTask`.

I am also very uncertain about where to make subclasses of these. One friend suggested extending `TimerTask` as an inner class in my `FeedParser` class to make it simpler. However, to implement it in that way, I have to use the `run()` method for `TimerTask` without overriding it, meaning I can't simply use the parameters I need for the functions that need to run.

In short, what is the best way to schedule the tasks for this, and where would I implement these?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I prefer to use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. Generally, if I understand your requirements correctly, all these can be implemented in your activity, TimerTask and Handler are not needed, see sample code below:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    // This schedule a task to run every 10 minutes:
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // Parsing RSS feed:
        myFeedParser.doSomething();

        // If you need update UI, simply do this:
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            // update your UI component here.
            myTextView.setText("refreshed");
          }
        });
      }
    }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  } // end of onCreate()
}
```

Remember to finish/close your runnable task properly in Activity.onDestroy(), hope that help.

Comment: So is it preferred to actually use `ScheduledExecutorService` rather than `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, which is a subclass of the former? Or is it just that I don't need the added things in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`?

Comment: As you said, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor is a ScheduledExecutorService, which one to use is totally up to you.

Comment: Very helpful answer, how do you go about "finishing/closing your runnable task properly" all the examples I found used a handler/timer to accomplish this and removeCallbacks.  Anyone know the process for ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: I am trying this method out for a periodic task, but it does not seem to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872016/scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-for-a-periodic-task-using-retrofit-just-firing-onc

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, worked for me. Just one issue, is it possible to suspend the UI updates in `onPause()` to avoid queueing up numerous UI updates (in my case `alertDialog`).