# How can i stop a TimerTask Handler?

Tags: android, handler, timertask

I am trying to stop a Timer or TimerTask, but the method doesn't destroy the task...

First the code how i set up the timertask:

```
 scanTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                     load_unread();
                     Log.d("TIMER", "Timer set off");
                    }
           });
    }};
```

t=new Timer();
    t.schedule(scanTask, 300, 10000);

and now I'm trying to "kill" this Task at onDestroy:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    scanTask.cancel();
    t.cancel();
    t.purge();
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    System.out.println("Chat destroyed");
}
```

but this doesn't work? Can you please help me finding a solution?

Thanks!

EDIT: I finally found the answer. Don't know why mine didn't work...

Here the code for everyone who has the same Problem. I think this is a better and more efficient solution anyway:

`private Handler handler = new Handler();
    runnable.run();`

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
{

    public void run() 
    {
         //
         // Do the stuff
         //

         handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

and to stop:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

taken from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11640073/1956197

Comment: Why doesn'it it work? Is it running, or are you getting an error?

Comment: It is running. there are no errors at all, but in my log I'm still getting this "timer set off" from the runnable.

Comment: So, you get "Chat destroyed" in log, and after that "timer set off", and the activity with the timer was not restarted, correct? Pretty weird, if yes.

Comment: exactly thats the problem... if my activity was restarted,i would get enother log because I'm catching the OnResume also...

Comment: is there another way to make a repeating function which i can cancel easier?

Comment: You can try handler postDelayed, and in handleMessage make postDelayed again to itself thus making an infinite posting.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your edit, the only thing I'd suggest is to use `handler.post(runnable);` instead of `runnable.run();` This way you are always executing your runnable on a separate thread.  Otherwise, your first execution will run on the main thread, then future executions run inside the handler on a separate thread.

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            //
            // Do the stuff
            //

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: oh ok that seems logic, this may have been the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the TimerTask before setting it to null.

```
scanTask.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

this example start the timer unitl destroyed

```
 private lateinit var timerTask: TimerTask

 timerTask = object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            Log.d("KTZ", "$minutes:$seconds");
            timeRecordingLiveData.postValue("$minutes:$seconds")
            seconds += 1;
            if (seconds == 60) {
                Log.d("KTZ", "$minutes:$seconds");
                timeRecordingLiveData.postValue("$minutes:$seconds")
                seconds = 0;
                minutes += 1;
            }
        }

    }
```

Cancel the timertask in onDestroy()

```
    timerTask.cancel()
```