# android thread does not run in standby

Tags: java, android, multithreading, standby

In my program, I'd like to check for a new version (getting data from `HTTP`).
The function works perfectly, but I want to have it running in background every X (configurable, one hour, one day, and so on).

So I wrote this code:

```
    Timer mTimer1 = new Timer();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.main.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = this.pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, MainActivity.PROGRAM);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl.acquire();
    TimerTask mTt1 = new TimerTask()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        mTimerHandler.post(new Runnable()
          {
            public void run()
            {
// Do the check...
            }
          });
      }
    };
```

(since this function is in a separate class NOT deriving from `Activity`, I passed to the constructor the parent class `this.main`, so that I can call `getSystemService`. This `Variable` is declared as `private MainActivity main`).
Well, when I start the `Timer` it checks for new version, then, after an hour (so my settings), I check in the `Logs` and I see that the thread did not run...

I searched in Internet and I found, that I have to use the `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`, and I do that...

Any idea, why I have this problem?

Thanks a lot!
Luca Bertoncello

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a SO answer that can help you with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639251/android-run-a-thread-repeatingly-within-a-timer) using a handler and postDelayed().

However, if you want to run this even when the app isn't open then you will want to use an [AlarmManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).You create a `PendingIntent` and create a `Calendar` instance to set the time you want it to check then use `setRepeating()` on the `AlarmManger`. This will have it check even when not in the app. You can also register it in the `manifest` as `Boot_Completed` so it will start running again after reboot when the device is turned off

[Here is a good example to get you started with AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082437/android-alarmmanager)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Timer, did you remember to schedule your TimerTask?
Try
    `mTimer1.schedule(mTt1, delay, interval);`

And if you want to stop that, do `mTimer1.cancel();`
and `mTimer1.purge();` to clear the schedule queue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
         timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( 
                    new java.util.TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                              // Your code
                   }},
                1000, 5000
                );
```

Where **1000** is a post delay , if you want delay for first time , if you don't want than put it **0**

**5000** is a iteration time

Answer (score 0):

When the phone goes to sleep, execution will be paused for your activity and thus your timer will never fire. Using `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` is probably not a good idea as it will consume battery the entire time your phone sleeps.

I would suggest taking a look at [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and specifically [setInexactRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)