# public void onCreate() { does not execute

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, android-pendingintent

For some strange reason nothing in this code will execute after the  public void onCreate() { command

P.S.

I've run a debug session on this and it appears it stops at:

```
return START_STICKY;
    }
    return startId;
}
```

...and never continues to start:

```
 startServiceTimer();
```

Any / all suggestions are greatly appreciated!

SOURCE:

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;

    public static final String swappedMdn(Context ctx) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        // Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
        String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();

        // Insure MDN is 10 characters
        if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null)
            mdn = "0000000000";

        // Extract last 10 digits of MDN
        if (mdn.length() > 10)
            mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length());
        char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
        char digit;
        for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length()) % 2; index += 2) {
            digit = data[index];
            data[index] = data[index + 1];
            data[index + 1] = digit;

            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DataCountService.class);

            SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
                    Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
            Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("0", new String(data));
            editor.commit();

        }

        return String.valueOf(data);

    }

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (intent == null) {

            // Exit gracefully if service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {

            if (extras != null) {

                String newMdn = swappedMdn(this);

                text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;1")) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

                    // get the date
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "hh/mm/ss/MM/dd/yy");
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    String tag = ";";

                    // String mdn =
                    // extras.getString(DataCountUtilities.swappedMdn(this));
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String DToDevice = s.format(new Date());
                    String status = (settings.getString("status", "0"));
                    String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag + status
                            + tag + settings.getString("0", newMdn) + tag
                            + DToDevice + tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr + settings.getString("last_month", "0"));
                    info = "USI" + info.replace("USI", "");

                    // info = (info.replace("CN", "CO")).replace("WN", "WO");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(info);
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO");
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO");
                    info = b.toString();

                    // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                                null);

                        // set status to enabled
                        Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("status", "1");
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();

                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null, info, null,
                                null);
                    }
                }

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
            } else if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                    "//USR;0")) {

                // set status to disabled
                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("status", "0");
                editor.commit();
                stopSelf();

            }

            return START_STICKY;
        }
        return startId;
    }

    private void StartActivity(android.content.Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Intent Intent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {

            period = Constants.PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DELAY_INTERVAL;

        } else {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            period = Constants.DEBUG_PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL;
        }
        startServiceTimer();
    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            // public void run() {
            // @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {

                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("callMade", "1");
                    editor.commit();



                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats
                            .getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats
                            .getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String tag = ";";
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag,
                            mobileStr, totalStr);

                    // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences
                    SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME,
                                    0);
                    //Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_month", info);
                    editor.commit();

                    // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data
                    // usage) and save the current time
                    String sms = "";
                    sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                    sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, sms
                                + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                null, null);
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                null, null);
                    }





                } else {

                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    if (settings.getString("callsMade", "1").equals(1)) {

                        // SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        // .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        if (settings.getString("status", "0").equals(1)) {

                            // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                            double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats
                                    .getTotalRxBytes()
                                    + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                            double mobileBytes = TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileRxBytes()
                                    + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                            totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                            totalBytes /= 1000000;
                            mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                            String tag = ";";
                            String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                            String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                            String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag,
                                    mobileStr, totalStr);

                            // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences
                            SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                                    .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME,
                                            0);
                            Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                            editor.putString("last_month", info);
                            editor.commit();

                            // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data
                            // usage) and save the current time
                            String sms = "";
                            sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                            sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                                    + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                                            .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                                            .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                                String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                        Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                        Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                                smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, sms
                                        + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                        null, null);
                                editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                        System.currentTimeMillis());
                                editor.commit();
                            } else {
                                SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                        Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                        sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                        null, null);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, delay_interval, period);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

CONSTANTS:

```
public final class Constants {



    //Timer Constants
    public static final long SMS_TIMER = 2592000000L; // 15 days 
    public static final long DEBUG_SMS_TIMER = 300000; // 5 minutes 
    public static final long PERIOD =  3600000; // one hour 
    public static final long DELAY_INTERVAL = 0; 
    public static final long DEBUG_PERIOD = 15000; // 15 seconds
    public static final long DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL = 0;
```

EDIT:

```
DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;

    public static final String swappedMdn(Context ctx) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        // Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
        String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();

        // Insure MDN is 10 characters
        if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null)
            mdn = "0000000000";

        // Extract last 10 digits of MDN
        if (mdn.length() > 10)
            mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length());
        char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
        char digit;
        for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length()) % 2; index += 2) {
            digit = data[index];
            data[index] = data[index + 1];
            data[index + 1] = digit;

            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DataCountService.class);

            SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
                    Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
            Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("0", new String(data));
            editor.commit();

        }

        return String.valueOf(data);

    }

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (intent == null) {

            // Exit gracefully if service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {

            if (extras != null) {

                String newMdn = swappedMdn(this);

                text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;1")) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

                    // get the date
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "hh/mm/ss/MM/dd/yy");
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    String tag = ";";

                    // String mdn =
                    // extras.getString(DataCountUtilities.swappedMdn(this));
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String DToDevice = s.format(new Date());
                    String status = (settings.getString("status", "0"));
                    String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag + status
                            + tag + settings.getString("0", newMdn) + tag
                            + DToDevice + tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr + settings.getString("last_month", "0"));
                    info = "USI" + info.replace("USI", "");

                    // info = (info.replace("CN", "CO")).replace("WN", "WO");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(info);
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO");
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO");
                    info = b.toString();

                    // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                                null);

                        // set status to enabled
                        Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("status", "1");
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();

                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null, info, null,
                                null);
                    }
                }

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
            } else if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                    "//USR;0")) {

                // set status to disabled
                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("status", "0");
                editor.commit();
                //stopSelf();

                return flags;

            }

            return START_STICKY;
        }
            if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {

                period = Constants.PERIOD;
                delay_interval = Constants.DELAY_INTERVAL;

            } else {
            //  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                period = Constants.DEBUG_PERIOD;
                delay_interval = Constants.DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL;
            }
            startServiceTimer();


        return startId;
    }

    private void StartActivity(android.content.Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Intent Intent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {


    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            // public void run() {
            // @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {

                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("callMade", "1");
                    editor.commit();



                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats
                            .getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats
                            .getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String tag = ";";
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag,
                            mobileStr, totalStr);

                    // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences
                    SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME,
                                    0);
                    //Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_month", info);
                    editor.commit();

                    // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data
                    // usage) and save the current time
                    String sms = "";
                    sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                    sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, sms
                                + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                null, null);
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                null, null);
                    }





                } else {

                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    if (settings.getString("callsMade", "1").equals(1)) {

                        // SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        // .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        if (settings.getString("status", "0").equals(1)) {

                            // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                            double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats
                                    .getTotalRxBytes()
                                    + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                            double mobileBytes = TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileRxBytes()
                                    + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                            totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                            totalBytes /= 1000000;
                            mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                            String tag = ";";
                            String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                            String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                            String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag,
                                    mobileStr, totalStr);

                            // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences
                            SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                                    .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME,
                                            0);
                            Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                            editor.putString("last_month", info);
                            editor.commit();

                            // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data
                            // usage) and save the current time
                            String sms = "";
                            sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                                    .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                            sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                                    + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                                            .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                                            .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                                String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                        Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                        Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                                smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, sms
                                        + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                        null, null);
                                editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                        System.currentTimeMillis());
                                editor.commit();
                            } else {
                                SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                        Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                        sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""),
                                        null, null);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, delay_interval, period);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a rather complex chunk of code you've asked for help on. Any chance of simplifying it? See http://sscce.org/

Comment: How is your Service created in your Activity?

Comment: I removed the non-relevant code from the constants class - but I don't think I can trim down the datacountservice without possibly removing what is causing the issue. (BTW - everything works fine - if you send it an sms - it returns the sms with the correct data - the only thing that does not happen is it never reaches oncreate - everything above that works just fine)

Comment: @Rob013 the service is started when it receives an sms containing the code //USR;1

Answer (score 0):

Put your `onCreate()` code at the bottom of `onStartCommand` and everything will work.

Little explaination (refer to Internet or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182014/android-oncreate-or-onstartcommand-for-starting-service) for a better one):

`onCreate()` is called whenever a Service is **created**, if you manually instantiate it.

`onStartCommand()`, instead, is called whenever / wherever you use `startService(intent)`.

That's why, sometimes, you feel like `onCreate()` has skipped.

Comment: before `return startId;` but it really depends on your desired logic. If you wanted onCreate() to be called before onStartCommand(), just place that code as the first lines in `onStartCommand` or viceversa.

Comment: @user2528574 you have to **remove** your onCreate :P Just take its code and put it inside your `onStartCommand` function.

Comment: I updated my source as suggested (shown above) I still cant get the code to repeat as it should every 15 seconds

Comment: But now, at least, startServiceTimer() should have been called, hasn't it? Probably the problem is elsewhere. Here there are a few solution for repeating code in a service though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639251/android-run-a-thread-repeatingly-within-a-timer

Comment: I set a breakpoint at private void startServiceTimer() { but it still does not reach it

Comment: @user2528574 you really need to take a deep breath and then come back to your problem. You have an if/else statement and you have     `return START_STICKY;` when intent is not null. Remove that start_sticky and, if there are other issue, face them reading line per line ;)

Comment: I also tried setting a breakpoint at startServiceTimer();
   and it does not reach it either

Comment: Also I set a breakpoint in the very beginning and followed it the entire way through... it appears it hits return START_STICKY; skips over startservice timer and goes right to return startId;

Comment: It appears I have "dead code" at  (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {

    period = Constants.PERIOD;
    delay_interval = Constants.DELAY_INTERVAL;

   } else {
   // Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    period = Constants.DEBUG_PERIOD;
    delay_interval = Constants.DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL;
   }
   startServiceTimer();


any idea how I can resolve that to get the startServiceTimer(); to execute?