# Is it wrong to do runnable.run()?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am fairly new to the concept of multithreading and there is an aspect which is not clear to me.

There are two ways to create and run a thread:

1. Extend a Thread class and `start()` the thread.
2. Create a Runnable object, pass it to a `Thread` constructor and `start()` the thread.

And [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html#common-pitfall) blog post states that we always should start a thread using a `start()` or so was my impression of it.

But in one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639251/android-run-a-thread-repeatingly-within-a-timer) you could see how a person is using `runnable.run()`.  It gives me an impression of somewhat wrong practice.

**Is it normal? Should it be avoided?** You can be explicit in your answer, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `run` is just a method declared in the `Runnable` interface. There's no magic.

Comment: ok. Should I run the runnable? Or start a Thread. Isn't runnable interface designed specifically to be used with a thread?

Comment: Sure, primarily. And internally, `Thread` simply does call `run` on the `Runnable` instance you pass it. There's nothing preventing you from doing the same. But note, that that alone does not start a thread.

Comment: Aha... So if I enclose some statements in runnable and do .run() it simply means that I execute these statements sequentially, like I would otherwise?

Comment: That's exactly right. The `Thread` class is the one doing the thread magic.

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much answers my question.

Comment: The `run` method simply does the work. The `Thread` class actually represents the thread which executes the `run` method and burdens itself with the work defined by `run`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're just different things. `run()` executes the Runnable in the current thread. Calling `start()`, on the other hand, causes the Runnable to run in the new thread.

The tutorial points it out as a pitfall. You went through all that trouble to make a thread, so if you go on to run it in the current thread instead, then it's likely a mistake.