# How to make a service to loop constantly?

Tags: java, android, service

I have a service which is started by a BroadcastReceiver that activates when the boot is completed. So the service starts and I have the following on my onStartCommand

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

      //FROM NOW ON I WANT IT TO LOOP CONSTANTLY
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, API.getDeviceTypes(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        processResponse(response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("mytag", "Error de response");
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            mQueue.add(request);
          // LOOP TILL HERE



    return START_STICKY;
}
```

I want the service to make that request constantly or at least every 3 minutes or something. How can I achieve this?
As of now the service starts ok but of course it only executes those lines once.

Comment: https://github.com/evernote/android-job
Try above solution

Comment: Create a new thread, call this function in while loop and then at the end of each iteration call thread sleep for 3 minutes

Comment: @AmanChhabra I'm unfamiliar with threads, could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @RissmonSuresh Isn't there a solution without using an external repository?

Comment: @Stackoverflowed Check my answer provided below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `Handler` for your requirement do not use `Thread` it will block
>   **Main UI Thread**

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      handler = new Handler();
        if (runnable != null) {
            runnable = null;
        }
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do your stuff here, called every 3 second
                mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

      //FROM NOW ON I WANT IT TO LOOP CONSTANTLY
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, API.getDeviceTypes(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        processResponse(response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("mytag", "Error de response");
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            mQueue.add(request);
                h.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
        };

// start it with:
handler.post(runnable);

 return START_STICKY;


}
```

**And dont forget to remove handler callback also in onDestroy() or in onstop according to your need**

```
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    handler.removeMessages(0);
```

Read why handler is better  from here 
[difference between Thread and Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761351/difference-between-thread-and-handler)

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying your alternative. What type of variable is 'h'?

Comment: h is Handler object which is handler ,user handler instead of h dear and let me know if there is any issue

Comment: Edited my answer also

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help, it worked perfectly.

Comment: I am glad it worked dear ,Upvote my answer just below the down arrow which will let other people to use my answer and refer it also ,thanks HAPPY CODING

Answer (score 1):

**AlarmManager** can be used to perform a task periodically:

Let’s say we want to perform a task after every 3 minutes.

> setRepeating() allows to schedules an alarm with exact repeating time.

```
AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                              180000+System.currentTimeMillis(),
                                  getPendingIntent(ctxt));
```

and you can get pending intent

```
// Specify ur receiver
    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context ctxt) {
        Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, APIReceiver.class);
        return(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, i, 0));
    }
```

You can stop alarm manager by calling:

```
public void stopAlarmManager()
{          
    if(alarmMgr != null)
       alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```