# Update UI continously android

Tags: android, asynchronous, service, timer

In my application, I want to update my UI continuously after 2 seconds. Which is the most suitable method to update.

1. Timer
2. Async task or anything else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11640073/3713967

Comment: For UI use UIThread in a service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Define a Runnable:**

```
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       //Update to your UI
    }
};
```

**Inside your continuous thread:**

```
runOnUiThread(mRunnable);
```