# Androids Calendar.MINUTE does not return the correct Minute

Tags: android, android-calendar

So I have a loop that i want to poll data every 5 minutes to keep my api requests down to a minimum.  The problem is that CurrentMin does not update when the minute on the android phone does.  It starts off correct but then fails to stay current.  Any ideas how I can make this poll data every 5 minutes?

```
while (x==false) {
    currentMin= c.get(Calendar.MINUTE); //get the current min
    System.out.println(currentMin);

    if (currentMin%5==0) {//poll the data every 5 min
        ***Poll data***
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you get you create a Calendar instance, it will store the time at which it was created, it is not meant to be polled. I'd use a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to achieve what you're looking for! Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098806/where-do-i-create-and-use-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-timertask-or-handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [How to run a method every X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434056/how-to-run-a-method-every-x-seconds):

Use a `Handler`. Never, and i mean **never** schedule tasks with a `while` in Android. Your battery will dry within minutes, you will lock your UI and make your application slow.

```
Handler h = new Handler();
int delay = 1000; //interval in milliseconds

h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //pool data
        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `TimerTask`. Looping aproach is a pretty bad choice.

Here is an example of the usage of it

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-timertask-example/

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) as follows:

```
private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor mScheduleTaskExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
mScheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRequestRunnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And yourRequestRunnable will be something like:

```
Runnable yourRequestRunnable = new Runnable() {
    // Do your request here
}
```

This will basically guarantee you will execute code at a fixed rate. If you need to do something in the UI after the request is done, just wrap the code that handles UI changes on a `runOnUiThread()`